# How long should a "remember me" token be?

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to add "remember me" functionality to a website using a cookie with the user's username and a token, which is also stored encrypted in a database. My question is how long should this token be? [One website I read](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) said 128bit, which in my thinking is 16 characters. I'm not too worried about duplicates as even 16 characters from a character set of 256 characters provides a huge number of possibilites and the chance of duplicates at the same time is slim.

How long should the token be? (I'm not wondering about how to generate the value or how unique.)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website that you mention in your question.  Are you asking how long the value stored in the cookie should be or how you should generate that value and what it should relate too?

Comment: Revised the question & added link to website.

Comment: Why do you need to know what the "right" length is? There is no right here. How can you not care about how to generate it but care about the length? They are closely related.

Comment: I dont' care about how to generate it because I have 20 different way to generate a key. I'm wondering about length because I am unsure about that. I know they are closely related, but only 1 person seems to have got the point of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends more on how the value is randomised than how long it is.  A 256 bit hash is not secure at all if it's just a hash of something that can easily be guessed or narrowed down such as a unique ID based on the time.

However, as you've said, you are not specifically asking about how to make it random enough.

An estimated 2^80 (or more) required operations in order to break something is usually a good measure.  This would imply an 80 bit hash is secure.  (If you were vulnerable to birthday attacks, you'd need double that ie 160 bits, but I don't think this situations applies).

Personally, for this purpose I use 256 bit hashes.  When base64 encoded, they compress down to only 43 characters in length, all printable characters.  I figure that even though it's way more than what I need, it's not a big hassle having them that long.

Comment: Umm, a GUID can't be easily guessed or narrowed down in most situations.

Answer (score 7):

Just use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier). Many databases support them as a native type; they're easy to manipulate in most popular languages/frameworks; translate perfectly from one platform to another; and [every one is unique](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000399.html).

Comment: Sorry, I guess it wasn't clear. I'm wondering about the length.

Comment: A GUID implies a length -- the 128 bits / 16 characters that you mention in your question.

Comment: I am looking for what length it should be. Is 16 the correct length?

Comment: @Darryl for transmission and plain-text storage (like cookies), a GUID is usually encoded to HEX, which is 32 characters.

Comment: v4 UUIDs should be fine and are easy to get and work with, and have the benefit you're leveraging other people's work who probably have more time to think about this issue than any of the rest of us do. However, just be aware the [RFC on UUIDs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-6) specifically states "they should not be used as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants access)".

Answer (score 0):

You can always just look at what others have done, like [Oauth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.10) which suggests the token be between 128 and 160 bits, and do the same. I like [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/7945/12049), which says 122 bits should be adequate "for most purposes, including launch codes for nuclear missiles." Which is funny if you believe the actual launch code [may have been 00000000 for 20 years](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/12/launch-code-for-us-nukes-was-00000000-for-20-years/). So much for the security of our 160 bit tokens.